# How to call worklight adapter from other adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

How to call method of one adapter from the method of other adapter?

Suppose, I have two adapters :

**1. ReadAdapter that has method ReadFile.**

**2. CreateAdapter that has method CreateFile**

Now I wants to call ReadFile method of ReadAdapter from CreateAdapter's CreateFile method.

Is it possible in Worklight 6.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please look at the following presentation which outlines this exact behavior:

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/04_07_Advanced_adapter_usage_and_mashup.pdf

Worklight even provides a corresponding sample to compliment the presentation:

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/AdapterMashUpProject.zip

The sample above shows a project with multiple adapters with the following structure:

[image]

The sample even provides code snippets for calling one adapter from another such as:

[image]